# Magento 2: how to call checkout session in controller?

Tags: magento2, checkout, controllers, session

Please anyone tell me, how to call checkout session in module's controller?

this method doesn't work for me

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo;


class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {

        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump($this->_checkoutSession);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share how it isn't working. What error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 8):

You can just try using below method,

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo;


class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {

        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump($this->_checkoutSession->getData());exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, your response doesn't work i got this error:


There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 326878733088

Comment: Have a look in the var/report folder and see the error message in the "326878733088" file.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor, you need to make sure you call the parent::__construct method with the $context.

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
<?php

namespace Demo\Demo\Controller\Demo;

class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface  */
    protected $messageManager;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Direct use of object manager is not a good practice in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

public function execute()
{
var_dump($this->_checkoutSession->getQuoteId());exit;
}