# Magento 2 Increment id

Tags: magento2, object-manager

**How can I get increment_id on  Magento 2 checkout page?**

```
 >$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   >$quoteId = $objectManager-> create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuoteId();///session user quote_Id
```

Im using objectManager to get quote_id, is there a solution using the same way?

Comment: Do you want to Order Increment Id on checkout page? Which need to assign this quote?

Answer (score -1):

Using inject `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` to constructor

Comment: Could you please show me an example? I´m stuck trying to get this information.

Comment: You can try with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/magento-2-how-to-call-checkout-session-in-controller and call  `$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote->getId()` or  `$this->_checkoutSession->getQuoteId()`